# what should be location of BroadcastReceiver java file?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Here comes a really stupid question.
I am trying to create an App which requires to start automatically at every boot up of the mobile. I googled and searched stackoverflow too much and came to undertstand that I need to do these two things

First is this piece of code which must be put in to AndroidMainfest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.onRestartReciever">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />
            <data android:scheme="package" android:path="my.Package.Path" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Second is that I need to make a .java file with the code like this

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  /* 
   * after reboot widget appears to stop working and becomes unresponsive to clicks
   * this broadcast receiver will create new alarm and refresh pending intents
   */

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
  {
    /* do your stuff here, mostly just copy&paste from other places */
  }
}
```

The thing is I cant make up where to put this java file. I mean which folder ? and will I have to Include it somewhere to use it ?
I am really really sorry to ask for direct answers but I don't have any prior knowledge of this and I am stuck with this problem from last three days. help me please.

A tutorial will also be very very helpful related to the same topic (I couldn't find any)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name is exactly what u have used than put your java class in a folder named recievers in src package..In recievers folder add ur .java file named onRestartReciever...Change ur java file name from BootReciever to onRestartReciever..

Answer (score 0):

**src** folder of your project!!..

Below are some examples for using BR

[Tutorial for Broadcast receiver](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

[Tutorial 2](http://androidword.blogspot.in/2010/10/how-to-use-broadcast-receiver.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put your BootReceiver in your source code (New Java class in src folder) anywhere you want. And when device is rebooted your onReceive method will be called. Then you can start activity/service etc...